# Set sysfs network option before interface is up

Tags: linux, configuration-management, sysctl, dhcpcd

I want to set `/sys/class/net/wwan0/qmi/raw_ip`, and I don't want to do it by writing a shell script to take `wwan0` down set it, then put `wwan0` back up as a systemd unit. I'm trying this on Raspbian Stretch, but I doubt the distribution matters much for this.

I tried a bunch of ways of expressing this as a kernel cmdline argument, with no luck (`net.qmi.raw_ip=Y`, `net.qmi_wwan.raw_ip=Y`, `qmi_wwan.raw_ip=Y`, etc).

I tried adding `net.wwan0.qmi.raw_ip=1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf`. That produced this error: `[   23.918756] qmi_wwan 1-1.5:1.3 wwan0: Cannot change a running device`
Which means that it didn't do it until `wwan0` was already up.

I tried adding `denyinterfaces wwan0` to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, but same result.

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting `echo Y > /sys/class/net/wwan0/qmi/raw_ip` inside your `rc.local`.

A more convenient solution is to add the above line to the qmi shell script and finally call this during your `ifdown` & `ifup` actions on the interface.

For more information refer to this guide: https://embeddedpi.com/documentation/3g-4g-modems/raspberry-pi-sierra-wireless-mc7455-modem-raw-ip-qmi-interface-setup